# resource drbd not migrating to other node manually

Tags: pacemaker

I have two nodes corosync and pacemaker
The funds are vip, apache, and drbd.
All work. But if I migrate the drbd resource to another node it goes to all other resources and nothing is migrated. If I restart or standby or put anything not migrate. However the resource is started on the source node or whether this fixed in the same nó.mas have not configurate force to rotate in the same node. And in the logs I see many blocked messages when trying to migrate, this may be because of the network. Or it could be a conf corosync or something on the network that blocks multicast.
Thanks to those who help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DRBD alone (without pacemaker), can you switch the Master ?

drbd rosource is master/slave type, is NOT active/standby type.
If you use `pcs` as the setting tool, setting example is follows:

```
# pcs resource create drbd ocf:linbit:drbd \
    drbd_resource="r0" \
    op monitor interval="10s" role="Master" timeout="20s" \
    op monitor interval="20s" role="Slave" timeout="20s" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="60s" \
    op stop interval="0" timeout="60s" \
    op promote interval="0" timeout="60s" \
    --master meta master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1 notify=true
```

Please disclosure your software version, configurations and logs.